# Deploy a Meteor project to my own domain?

Tags: deployment, upload, meteor, project, dreamhost

I want to deploy my Meteor project to my own domain. In the docs it says:

"You can also deploy to your own domain. Just set up the hostname you want to use as a CNAME to origin.meteor.com, then deploy to that name.

$ meteor deploy www.myapp.com
We provide this as a free service so you can try Meteor. It is also helpful for quickly putting up internal betas, demos, and so on."

Is this what I need to do? What does this even mean? I don't know what a CNAME is or how to set up my hostname.

Comment: And you've tried . . . ? And you've read http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying, particularly the section called 'Running on your own infrastructure', and found it unfulfilling somehow?

Comment: This process generally requires quite a few steps if you're not deploying through Meteor.  Have you done any research into deploying in general?  Do you have a remote server?  A domain name isn't a server - you can't upload to a domain name.  I may try and use `Meteor deploy` at this point if I were you.

Comment: You can get a [free small Micro instance from AWS for a year](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html) if you're so inclined.

Comment: I have a domain hosted through dreamhost

Comment: I tried using $ meteor bundle myapp.tgz but it says "command not found"

Comment: Are you on windows?  If so, don't type the $.  After that, look for help deploying node.js onto dreamhost.  (It's more common than Meteor, but a similar process.  Sadly, this link seems to say it would be against your term of service:

https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-129095.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy Meteor on your own domain, I wrote a tutorial on the subject. If you are running Nginx, it should help you. Otherwise, if you are running Apache, check the second one.

[Deploy a Meteor Application on Ubuntu with Nginx.](http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-1-deploy-a-meteor-application-on-ubuntu-with-nginx/)

[Deploy a Meteor Application on Ubuntu with Apache.](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/deploy-meteorjs-vhosts-ubuntu1204-mongodb-apache-proxy)

And of course, you need to understand and configure your DNS. This two tutorials helped me a few months ago.

[An Introduction to DNS Terminology, Components, and Concepts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/an-introduction-to-dns-terminology-components-and-concepts)

[How To Set Up a Host Name with DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean)

Answer (score 2):

Over a year late but perhaps relevant for anyone else with this question, since the comments and answer given seem to miss the point - which is not about deploying to your own server but rather configuring meteor.com hosting to use a custom domain.

Meteor.com offer a free service that is intended for demos and internal betas - the very early days in the life of a site.

You can use meteor deloy without configuration if you are deploying to a subdomain on meteor.com -

```
meteor deploy myGreatHope.meteor.com
```

However you can also host your app on meteor.com using your own domain but to do that you need to be able to set up an alias which is done through CNAME A records

These are setup on a server that would otherwise host your site - So you will need a host - it could be really cheap one, and it could provide email hosting for you, ask them to create the A records (or look up your control panel help files) so that they resolve to origin.meteor.com and then you have your site, deployed to meteor.com accessible through your domain name.